Large $x$ behavior for the sum $\sum _{m=1} ^{\infty} \frac{x^{m(A+B)}}{\Gamma(m+1)^A\cdot \Gamma \left( m+\frac12 \right)^B}$
Consider the sum $S$ given by
$$S_{A,B}(x) =\sum _{m=1} ^{\infty} \frac{x^{m(A+B)}}{\Gamma(m+1)^A\cdot \Gamma \left( m+\frac12 \right)^B}, \quad \text{where}~~ A,B \in \mathbb{N}$$
Wolfram Mathematica gives some interesting closed forms for some specific values of $A, B$, for example:
$$
S_{1,1}(x) = \frac{2 \sinh ^2 x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\\
S_{2,2}(x) = \frac{-2 + I_0(4x) +J_0(4x)}{2\pi}
$$
But I am mostly interested in the asymptotic behavior of $S_{A,B}(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ for fixed $A$ and $B$. If I had to guess it would grow like $x^x$ but is this correct?

Heuristically, I got
$$S_{a,b}(x) =\sum {m=1}^\infty\frac{x^{m(a+b)}}{\Gamma(m+1)^a\cdot \Gamma \left( m+\frac12 \right)^b}\sim\frac{(2\pi)^\frac{1-a-b}2}{\sqrt{a+b}},e^{(a+b)x},x^\frac{1-a}2;,,a+b>0$$
What is correct numerically (WA check) and reproduces the asymptotic of $,S{1,1}$ at $,x\to\infty$. Next asymptotic terms can also be evaluated.

@Svyatoslav The method outlined here should provide a rigorous argument.

@Gary, thank you very much!

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are real and positive. Following the steps outlined here, we obtain
$$\tag{1}
S_{A,B} (x) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^{(A + B)t} }}{{\Gamma ^A (t + 1)\Gamma^B\! \left( {t + \frac{1}{2}} \right) }}{\rm d}t}  + \mathcal{O}(1)
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. The main contribution to the integral originates from the neighbourhood of the point $t= x\gg 1$. Using the asymptotics of the gamma function, it is straightforward to show that
$$
\frac{{x^{(A + B)t} }}{{\Gamma ^A (t + 1)\Gamma^B\! \left( {t + \frac{1}{2}} \right) }} \sim \frac{1}{{(2\pi )^{(A + B)/2} }}t^{ - A/2} \left( {\frac{{x{\rm e}}}{t}} \right)^{(A + B)t} 
$$
for large $t$. Then, applying Laplace's method, we deduce
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{(2\pi )^{(A + B)/2} }}t^{ - A/2} \left( {\frac{{x{\rm e}}}{t}} \right)^{(A + B)t} {\rm d}t}  &\mathop  = \limits^{t = xw} \frac{{x^{1 - A/2} }}{{(2\pi )^{(A + B)/2} }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {w^{ - A/2} {\rm e}^{ - (A + B)xw(\log w - 1)} {\rm d}w}\\  & \;\,\sim \frac{{x^{(1 - A)/2} {\rm e}^{(A + B)x} }}{{(2\pi )^{(A + B - 1)/2} \sqrt {A + B} }},
\end{align*}
as $x\to+\infty$. Therefore, we conclude that
$$
S_{A,B} (x) \sim \frac{{x^{(1 - A)/2} {\rm e}^{(A + B)x} }}{{(2\pi )^{(A + B - 1)/2} \sqrt {A + B} }}
$$
as $x\to+\infty$.
Addendum. A complete asymptotic expansion can be derived as follows. We first expand the gamma function expression into a factorial series:
$$
\frac{1}{{\Gamma ^A (t + 1)\Gamma ^B\! \left( {t + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}} \sim \frac{{(A + B)^{(A + B)t + A/2} }}{{(2\pi )^{(A + B - 1)/2} }}\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{c_j (A,B)}}{{\Gamma ((A + B)t + (A + 1)/2 + j)}}} 
$$
as $t\to+\infty$, with
$$
c_0 (A,B) = 1,\quad c_1 (A,B) = \frac{{A^2  + B^2  - AB - 1}}{{24}}.
$$
Next, applying equation $(1)$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
S_{A,B} (x) & \sim \frac{{(A + B)^{A/2} }}{{(2\pi )^{(A + B - 1)/2} }}\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {c_j (A,B)\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{((A + B)x)^{(A + B)t} }}{{\Gamma ((A + B)t + (A + 1)/2 + j)}}{\rm d}t} } 
\\ & = \frac{{x^{(1 - A)/2} }}{{(2\pi )^{(A + B - 1)/2} \sqrt {A + B} }}\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{c_j (A,B)}}{{((A + B)x)^j }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{((A + B)x)^{t + (A + 1)/2 + j - 1} }}{{\Gamma (t + (A + 1)/2 + j)}}{\rm d}t} } .
\end{align*}
For $z > 0$ and a fixed $\alpha >0$, consider the function
$$
F_\alpha(z) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{z^{t + \alpha  - 1} }}{{\Gamma (t + \alpha )}}{\rm d}t} .
$$
Assume that $\alpha\ge 1$. Noting that
$$
F_\alpha'(z) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{z^{t + \alpha  - 2} }}{{\Gamma (t + \alpha  - 1)}}{\rm d}t}  = F_\alpha(z) + \int_{ - 1}^0 {\frac{{z^{t + \alpha  - 1} }}{{\Gamma (t + \alpha )}}{\rm d}t} ,
$$
we obtain
\begin{align*}
F_\alpha(z){\rm e}^{ - z} & = \int_0^z {{\rm e}^{ - w} \left( {\int_{ - 1}^0 {\frac{{w^{t + \alpha  - 1} }}{{\Gamma (t + \alpha )}}{\rm d}t} } \right){\rm d}w}\\ &  = 1 - \int_z^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - w} \left( {\int_{ - 1}^0 {\frac{{w^{t + \alpha  - 1} }}{{\Gamma (t + \alpha )}}{\rm d}t} } \right){\rm d}w}  = 1 + \mathcal{O}({\rm e}^{ - z} z^{\alpha  - 1} ),
\end{align*}
as $z\to+\infty$. This asymptotics remains valid for $0<\alpha< 1$ since $F_\alpha  (z) = F_{\alpha  + 1} (z) + \int_{ - 1}^0 {\frac{{z^{t + \alpha } }}{{\Gamma (t + 1 + \alpha )}}{\rm d}t}  = F_{\alpha  + 1} (z) + \mathcal{O}(z^\alpha  )$. This leads to the asymptotic expansion
$$
S_{A,B} (x) \sim \frac{{x^{(1 - A)/2} {\rm e}^{(A + B)x} }}{{(2\pi )^{(A + B - 1)/2} \sqrt {A + B} }}\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  \frac{{c_j (A,B)}}{{((A + B)x)^j }} 
$$
as $x\to+\infty$.

Nice solution! (+1). Interestingly, next asymptotic term appears to be symmetric with respect to the permutation of $(A,B)$:
$$S_{A,B} (x) =\frac{{x^{(1 - A)/2} {\rm e}^{x(A + B)} }}{{(2\pi )^{(A + B - 1)/2} \sqrt {A + B} }}\left(1+\frac{A^2+B^2-AB}{24(A+B)},\frac1x+o\Big(\frac1{x}\Big)\right)$$

@Svyatoslav Have you taken into account the next term in the asymptotics of the gamma function expression? I belive the correction term shoul disappear when $A=B=1$ (cf. the explicit form).

I took the next term of the Stirling' approximation for $\Gamma(1+x)$ into consideration. But I think you are right about the asymptotic of the case $A=B=1$ - I agree that the correction term should vanish. I will check my evaluation. Thank you!

@Svyatoslav I added a simpler method for obtaining a complete asymptotic expansion. It seems that an extra $-1$ is missing in your first correction term.

This is an amazing answer! Thanks so much!

This is fantastic!
